# Proper way, that make a screen scrollable if the content is greater than the screen - Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am looking for the proper way, how can I use scrollable view only if necessary.

I want to create a card which will have an 500 height container. In this case some small-screen device could not show the content properly specially if the keyboard is showing.

In this case the screen should be scrollable, but I cant find a good solution.

I used a SingleChildScrollView with a Column child. Inside the column there was the Card view with the content.

Comment: singleChildScroll View is correct if you want to scroll "something" other than a list of items, which automatically has scrolling built in.

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html

Comment: what's wrong with SingleChildScrollView?